# Java constructor empty object

Tags: java, constructor, null, new-operator

my first time asking here so sorry if not asking properly

```java
public class Person
{
    private String name;
    private Date born;
    private Date died; //null indicates still alive.
    
    public Person(String initialName, Date birthDate, Date deathDate)
    {
        if (consistent(birthDate, deathDate))
        {
            name = initialName;
            born = new Date(birthDate);

            if (deathDate == null)
            {
                 died = null; 
            }
            else
            {
                 died = new Date(deathDate);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Inconsistent dates.Aborting.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

I have this code in my book. It is only part of the code, it is not a full code. I copied only the part that I was asking about. And my question is. Can't we just remove `if (deathDate == null)`. If it is `null`, then `died` will be `null` anyway?

Comment: Did you try it and use your IDE debugger to see if there's any difference?

Comment: It's pretty new. Also it is not a whole code if that's what wrong with it. I didn't try it because it's got lot of copying and pasting. I think it look wrong because this code is only a part of larger code

Comment: This is not a copy constructor. The copy constructor would have a signature like ``Public Person(Person p)``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep reading. There is an `else` statement. What you propose is to replace this:

```
if (deathDate == null) died = null;
else died = new Date(deathDate);
```

with:

```
died = new Date(deathDate);
```

which won't work; that would boil down to `new Date(null)` which will throw NullPointerException.

NB: This is *crazy* code. When a precondition fails (inconsistent dates), you throw an exception. You don't print something to standard err and exit the entire VM. Replace those last two lines with `throw new IllegalArgumentException("Death date cannot be before birth date. Death: " + death + " birth: " +birth);`.

Comment: Thanks, I understand this now. Also in the book it didnt explain yet about argument exceptions etc. It's probably in later chapers. Anyway, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You may as well replace the code:

```java
if (deathDate == null)
{
     died = null; 
}
else
{
     died = new Date(deathDate);
}
```

into this:

```java
died = null;
if (deathDate != null)
{
    died = new Date(deathDate);
}
```